# Android - embedding scrollView with other elements in one layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout, scrollable

I have a problem with my layout. I would like to show on one activity a toolbar on the top, below it I would like to have 2 image buttons and below those buttons a table which is embedded in a scrollView and filled in the activity dynamically.

So my final result should look smth. like this:

[image: Layout design]

My problem now is, that if I use a LinearLayout as the root element, nothing except the toolbar is shown:

[image: Result of the design when emulated]

The code to this layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#d3d3d3">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow_down"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/tableWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">

            <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:shrinkColumns="*"
                android:stretchColumns="*">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#16a085"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TableHeader"
                        android:layout_width="766dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_span="6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Data Base"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-83dp"></TextView>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow_item"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv1"
                        android:text="Table"
                        android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv2"
                        android:text="Action"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv3"
                        android:text="Request running"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv4"
                        android:text="Available"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="serif">       </TextView>
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I use a constraint layout instead of the linear layout as the root element, I can make all items running but the problem is, that the table in the scrollView has a margin to the top which leads the scollView not to be scrollable till the end of the table.
I also tried to exchange the margin by a padding (which was recommended in other posts) without success. Without the margin, the scroll view would work perfectly but cover the image buttons.

Any ideas how I can have all widgets on my layout and make the scrollView scrollable till the end even though?

Answer (score 0):

**first set height of `LinearLayout` that wraps `ImageButton` to `wrap_content` Also you can completely remove this `LinearLayout` since it has no `id` (can not be modified in java code) and is `vertical` as root `LinearLayout`**

then remove `LinearLayout` that wraps `ScrollView` completelty and change the `height` of `ScrollView` to `match_parent` and `TableLayout` to `wrap_content`

set height of root `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`

Following is the resulting code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#d3d3d3">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow_down"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/tableWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">

            <TableLayout 
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:shrinkColumns="*"
                android:stretchColumns="*">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#16a085"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TableHeader"
                        android:layout_width="766dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_span="6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Data Base"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-83dp"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow_item"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Table"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Action"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="serif"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Request running"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="serif"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Available"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="serif"/>
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Unfortunately no change.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to show the Table below the ImageButton it is showing on my device now. I have simply removed the margin-bottom from scrollView. And it does show that Linearlayout having a child a scroll view is unnecessary so if you want to remove it you can and one more thing I have added fillViewPort = true in scroll view maybe in future it would help.

The modified code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#d3d3d3">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow_down"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/tableWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">

            <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:shrinkColumns="*"
                android:stretchColumns="*">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#16a085"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TableHeader"
                        android:layout_width="766dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_span="6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Data Base"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-83dp"></TextView>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow_item"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv1"
                        android:text="Table"
                        android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv2"
                        android:text="Action"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv3"
                        android:text="Request running"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv4"
                        android:text="Available"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="serif">
                    </TextView>
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: @EmadEasa I am surprised how this could be working as the `LinearLayout` that wraps Image buttons is second child of root `LinearLayout` and its `layout_height` is set to `match_parent` so it will occupy all remaining space on the screen ignoring remaining childs requested height

Comment: @EmadEasa glad that it could help.

Comment: @EmadEasa I think is because the main Linear Layout i.e. the parent layout has height as wrap content.